# Add a Camera Preview

Tags: android, surfaceview, preview

I want my Activity background to be the Camera(Back) view,I have so far tried to add a surfaceView but no luck,the tutorials I found were for opening the camera app.
P.S- I do want to add more resources over the SurfaceView/Camera.
&
I don't want to click a picture only the preview
As I do not have any code to show as they are not what I need,so here is the [image: next best thing]  though it may have not been necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried something like this?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


      <SurfaceView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <!--views on top should come after the surfaceview, 
   at the same level    in the view heirarchy.
   this gives them a higher z-index (i.e. drawn afterwards)
   ... you could also use a RelativeLayout as the root view -->

      <ImageView
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp" 
      android:layout_gravity="center"/>



 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I have applied the code,I will let you know asap,And will this short code create a preview without any java class programming?

Comment: No, sorry, that is an example of the layout you must inflate in your activity in onCreate() so that you can put views on top of the camera background. The surface view needs to display frames received from the camera. Maybe this tutorial might help: http://blog.rhesoft.com/2015/04/02/tutorial-how-to-use-camera-with-android-and-android-studio/

Comment: A small help needed how do I Get the resources on the top